# Weather API Current Location City issue

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6

I am using weather api for my current location using **wunderground**. When the current location city is not available in the API the app get crashed. Now I want to redirect the nearby weather location city when current location city not available.

Here is my code,

```
 -(void) geoCodeUsingAddress:(NSString *)address
 {
    NSString       *esc_addr = [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *urlString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.wunderground.com/api/8e2edc55aaf7cfa7/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/%@.json",esc_addr];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    NSData *response1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSDictionary *alldicdata=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response1 options:0 error:nil];
    NSDictionary *forecast=[alldicdata objectForKey:@"forecast"];
    NSDictionary *simpleforecast=[forecast objectForKey:@"simpleforecast"];
    NSArray *arrofforecastday=[simpleforecast objectForKey:@"forecastday"];
    NSMutableArray *dataStore1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(NSDictionary *dict in arrofforecastday)
    {
    NSMutableDictionary *data=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [data setObject:[dict objectForKey:@"conditions"] forKey:@"conditions"];
```

Any way to redirect or find near by city available .Can any one please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at an error response:

```
{
    "response": {
        "version": "0.1",
        "termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
        "features": {
            "geolookup": 1,
            "conditions": 1,
            "forecast": 1
        },
        "error": {
            "type": "querynotfound",
            "description": "No cities match your search query"
        }
    }
}
```

I actually don't see how the code snippet you shared with us would crash (because on error, `forecast` would simply be `nil`, and thus so would would `simpleforecast`, `arrofforecastday`). You really should be testing if any of these are `nil` and handle that situation gracefully. I suspect you have some later code that assumes, for example, that one or more of these is not `nil` or that you successfully got inside that `for` loop.

Even better (i.e. in addition to the above point), you should test for an error reported by the server, you should say:

```
NSDictionary *response = [alldicdata objectForKey:@"response"];
NSDictionary *errorDictionary = [response objectForKey:@"error"];
NSDictionary *errorType = [errorDictionary objectForKey:@"type"];
NSDictionary *errorDescription = [errorDictionary objectForKey:@"description"];

if (errorType != nil)
{
    // handle the error here
}
```

Comment: also want to point out that OP has made a synchronous network call.

Comment: Agreed (assuming, of course, he is invoking geoCodeUsingAddress from the main queue). He really should be dispatching this code to a background queue using GCD `dispatch_async` or creating an operation queue and then invoking `addOperationWithBlock`. Or he should just perform `sendAsynchronousRequest` or use the `NSURLConnection` delegate methods.